# How to add alt to the image src tag in javascript execCommand methode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
'insert_img': { 
    "text": "Inserimage", 
    "icon":"icon icon-picture", 
    "tooltip": "Insertimage", 
    "commandname":null, 
    "custom": function(){ 
        var imgSrc = prompt('Enter image location', '');
        if (imgSrc != null) {
            document.execCommand('insertimage', false, imgSrc);
        } 
    } 
},
```

I have code like this, i want to give alt to image, how can i achieve this? when i take the source i wan to see `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face">` like this, Is it possible? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can't do it with the execCommand directly [Documentation of the commands](http://help.dottoro.com/larpvnhw.php) [an other one](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands).

You can still do it in jQuery, after adding the image (seems a bit hackish, I know, but don't think you can do better) :

```
$('img[src="smiley.gif"]').attr('alt','Smiley face');
```

Comment: I'm finding that execCommand() returns before the DOM is actually updated. So @MisterJ's suggestion requires some logic to ensure the new img element exists before adding the 'alt' attribute via JQuery.

Comment: Guess you could use MutationObserver on the contenteditable dom element : [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the insertHTML command like this:

```
document.execCommand('insertHTML', 0, '<img src="' + newUrlValue + '" alt="' + newAltValue + '" />');
```